# Android internal storage file writing is not working

Tags: android, internal-storage

I am new to android development. I've tried to write a file with a number in my android device . I could store the file in internal storage but I couldn't write on this file at this time.

This is my code .
Have any suggestions reveal to me.

```
        int count=0;
        FileOutputStream outputStream;
        BufferedReader input=null;
        File file=new File(getCacheDir(),"example.txt");
        if(file.exists()==true){
            try {
                input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
                String line;
                StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();
                while((line=input.readLine())!=null){
                    builder.append(line);
                }
                String g=builder.toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Count - " + g,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }catch (IOException e){

            }
        }else {
            try {
                count=count+1;
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                outputStream.write(count);
                outputStream.close();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"File - "+file.getPath().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }catch (IOException e){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error creating this file",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: @ChiragSavsani Thank you.

Comment: @ChiragSavsani - still not working

Comment: Now show my updated answer.

Comment: @ChiragSavsani - Give me couple of minutes

Answer (score 2):

> Add this line in Your AndroidManifest.xml File

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: then post your logcat here.

Comment: Actually I am working on a project so I couldn't post my logcat at this time.

Comment: Then post only exception which you got in your logcat.

Comment: There is no any exception in my logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone , I found a solution for my problem. I can do above work using a Sting instead of a integer. See you soon bye.